# Working with Koa,js and MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, koa

i have a problem or not even a problem just not enough knowledge about this, so the question is simple, i have code

```
router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
        let dbo = db.db("mydb");
        let query = {address: "Highway 37"};
        dbo.collection("customers").find(query).toArray((err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result)
            db.close();
        });
    });
    ctx.body = 'END OF FILE!!!';
});
```

console.log(result) i have my data and i need to response this data in ctx.body and i don;t know how to get result to my ctx.body, i am trying some options like create a variable and like let a, and a = result etc, however all hope is gone :)

Please any help will be appreciated, tnx a lot ^)

Answer (score 0):

Your handler could look like this:

```
router.get('/', ctx => {
  MongoClient.connect(..., (err, db) => {
    ...
    dbo.collection("customers").find(query).toArray((err, result) => {
      ctx.body = JSON.stringify(result)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: The problem is that i cannot return anything from this place
 dbo.collection("customers").find(query).toArray((err, result) => {
      "this place"
ctx.body = "Some text"; <= does not working here :(
    })

Comment: why not? you cannot send the body back until you have the data.

Comment: If i go like this - dbo.collection("customers").find(query).toArray((err, result) => {
            ctx.body = "Text inside dbo collection"
        });

i have Not Found in browser

console.log(ctx.body) instead of result - returns undefined